# Exporting Interactive Map as a HTML Issue in R

Tags: html, r, mapping

I have used the following code to produce a map on R. The issue is when I try and export as a HTML I get this error:

**popup.css not found in resource path**

When I export as a local html it works fine. Does anyone know why this is and how to fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#Load shape file
UK_Map<-gadm36_GBR_2_sp
plot(UK_Map)

#Retail Data and Postcodes
Benchmark_Retail <- read_excel("C:/Users/andrew.smith2/Desktop/Benchmark output_v3 (1920).xlsx")
Postcodes <- read_excel("C:/Users/andrew.smith2/Desktop/Postcodes.xlsx")

#Merge Datasets
Retail_data<-merge(Benchmark_Retail,Postcodes,by="Postcode")
Retail_data2<-as.tibble(Retail_data)
locations_sf <- st_as_sf(Retail_data2, coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4326)
m=mapview(locations_sf)
mapview(locations_sf)
mapshot(m, url = paste0(getwd(), "/map.html"))
```

Comment: Update to the latest development version and the error should go away. `remotes::install_github("r-spatial/mapview")`

Comment: Thank you so much @TimSalabim it works fine now. I do have a second question. Using mapview is it possible to change the colour of the latitude and longitude plots in the map based on value of a variable (in this case a benchmark rank of the stores?). Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with " latitude and longitude plots in the map"?